# How to source a file that has set of vim search and replace commands in vim interactively?

Tags: vim

I have a file (FileA) opened in Vim to edit. I have one another file (FileCommands) that has some set of vim search and replace commands.

I am looking to load that FileCommands file, to do that search and replace it in the FileA that I have opened in Vim. I found some other ways to do which are non-interactive, but I am looking for a way to do it interactively only when I need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While editing FileA:

```
$ vim FileA
```

Use the `:source` command to run the commands in FileCommands as Vimscript commands:

```
:source FileCommands
```

See [`:help :source`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#%3Asource) for more details.